# Предложение поступило МНЕ или КО МНЕ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, местоимение

> (Ко) мне поступило предложение.

Верно с предлогом "ко" или без него?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, лучше будет сказать, что предложение поступило мне. "Ко мне" — это, скорее, означает некое приближение. Вроде как принесли предложение и положили рядом. А "мне" уже означает, что предложение было сделано конкретно Вам.

Answer (score 1):

Контекст надо смотреть.
Но вообще-то в варианте "ко мне" фраза выглядит несколько странной. "Ко мне" - это не мне, это куда-то вообще, в мой дом, например.
Но и "мне" тоже небезгрешно. Может просто "Мне предложили"?

Comment: Конечно, предложенный Вами вариант тоже хорош, но все же хочется найти выход именно из этой ситуации :)

Comment: Понимаю. Но не всегда такой выход - удачное решение.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение поступает кому-либо или куда-либо:

> Моя супруга готовилась стать матерью, ей подошел срок рожать, и тут вдруг **мне поступило предложение** лететь в Цхинвал с итальянским журналистом из журнала Peace Reporter. [Алексей Пивоваров. После войны // «Русский репортер», № 48 (78), 18-25 декабря 2008, 2008]
>
> От нее-то **мне и поступило предложение** поставить Кристине программу. [Наталья Бестемьянова и др. Пара, в которой трое (2000-2001)]
>
> **Мне поступило несколько предложений** из московских школ, в том числе из моей. [Юлия Рахаева. Алексей Венедиктов: Деньги возьмем у старухи-процентщицы (2001) // «Известия», 2001.07.13]
>
> За год до Олимпийских игр в Калгари мне поступило предложение от знаменитого австралийского импресарио Майкла Эджли. [Татьяна Тарасова, Виталий Мелик-Карамов. Красавица и чудовище (1984-2001)]
>
> Сразу **двум министрам**, вице-премьеру Алексею Кудрину и главе МЭРТа Герману Грефу, **поступило предложение** войти в состав политсовета партии «Единая Россия». [Игорь Рябов. Коалиционная партия власти (2003) // «ПОЛИТКОМ. РУ», 2003.05.21]
>
> Выяснилось, что в рамках административной реформы **в аппарат правительства поступили предложения** лишить Минфин части функций, существенно влияющих на пополнение доходной части бюджета. [Татьяна Нетреба. Почему Кудрин такой неулыбчивый? // «Аргументы и факты», 2003]
>
> **В комиссию уже поступило несколько сотен предложений...**[Анна Закатнова. Библия без НДС (2003) // «Российская газета», 2003.03.15]